# RPATH applies for most of dependent libraries shown by ldd but not for all on Centos 7.7

Tags: c++, c, linux, linker, appimage

I have this problem only on CentOS 7.7 (on Fedora 33 and 35 it all works as expected). My appimage app for some reason tries to open system `libQt5Core.so.5`, `libsystemd.so.0` , and some others, while loading most other libraries from the appimage as intended.

I ensured to have `RPATH` (i.e., not even `RUNPATH`: I achieved it by using  `patchelf --force-rpath --set-rpath`) set up correctly for all the executable and libs. Below, I show the situation for my appimage after I extracted it with `--appimage-extract` option and applied `patchelf` to set `RPATH`:

```bash
[jenya@localhost bin]$ ldd myapp 
./myapp: /lib64/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15' not found (required by ./myapp)
./myapp: /lib64/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15' not found (required by /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5)
./myapp: /lib64/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15.2_PRIVATE_API' not found (required by /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5)
./myapp: /lib64/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15' not found (required by /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libQt5Gui.so.5)
./myapp: /lib64/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15.2_PRIVATE_API' not found (required by /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libQt5Gui.so.5)
./myapp: /lib64/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15.2_PRIVATE_API' not found (required by /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libQt5Sql.so.5)
./myapp: /lib64/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15' not found (required by /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libQt5Sql.so.5)
./myapp: /lib64/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15' not found (required by /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libQt5Network.so.5)
./myapp: /lib64/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15.2_PRIVATE_API' not found (required by /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libQt5Network.so.5)
./myapp: /lib64/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15.2_PRIVATE_API' not found (required by /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libQt5Test.so.5)
./myapp: /lib64/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.15' not found (required by /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libQt5Test.so.5)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcc2592000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007f2048415000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007f2047d9c000)
    libQt5Sql.so.5 => /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libQt5Sql.so.5 (0x00007f2048d47000)
    libQt5Network.so.5 => /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libQt5Network.so.5 (0x00007f2048b98000)
    libQt5Test.so.5 => /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libQt5Test.so.5 (0x00007f2047d41000)
--->libQt5Core.so.5 => /lib64/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f2047894000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f2047663000)
    libm.so.6 => /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f204751a000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f20474fe000)
    libc.so.6 => /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f204732c000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f2047308000)
    libGL.so.1 => /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f204726e000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007f2047233000)
    libz.so.1 => /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libz.so.1 (0x00007f2047218000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f2047146000)
    libdl.so.2 => /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f204713e000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f20470e5000)
    libssl.so.1.1 => /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007f2047042000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f2046d3e000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007f2046c78000)
    libicui18n.so.50 => /lib64/libicui18n.so.50 (0x00007f2046879000)
    libicuuc.so.50 => /lib64/libicuuc.so.50 (0x00007f2046500000)
    libicudata.so.50 => /lib64/libicudata.so.50 (0x00007f2044f2c000)
    libpcre2-16.so.0 => /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libpcre2-16.so.0 (0x00007f2044ea1000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f2044e9b000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f2044d5e000)
    ../lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2048b71000)
```

However, I have the `libQt5Core.so.5`, where it should be:

```bash
[jenya@localhost bin]$ ls /home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libQt5Core.so.5 
/home/jenya/Downloads/squashfs-root/usr/bin/./../lib/libQt5Core.so.5
```

Besides, I have ensured to have `RPATH` indeed, rather than `RUNPATH`:

```bash
[jenya@localhost bin]$ readelf -d ./myapp  | grep PATH
 0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [$ORIGIN/../lib]

[jenya@localhost bin]$ readelf -d ../lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5  | grep PATH
 0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [$ORIGIN]
```

How can this be and how can this be fixed? Thank you for attention.

Answer (score 0):

```
[jenya@localhost bin]$ objdump -s -j .note.ABI-tag ../lib/libQt5Core.so.5 

../lib/libQt5Core.so.5:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .note.ABI-tag:
 03a4 04000000 10000000 01000000 474e5500  ............GNU.
 03b4 00000000 03000000 11000000 00000000  ................
```

If one looks closely one can see `03 ... 11`. This says that it want kernel not younger than 3.17.

The solution by `strip`, proposed here https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/61130 and in some other places on the net did not help me.

So I installed `hexedit` and opened the lib with it. I made `/`-search of `1000000001000000474e5500`, and replaced `11` (i.e. 17) by `01` (just some version less than `3.10`, i.e. the version of Centos 7.7), and saved and exited (by `Ctrl+x`).

This did the trick.

Comment: Use following to remove the `.note.ABI-tag:` section `strip --remove-section=.note.ABI-tag <file path>`.

Comment: In my case it didn't help. I got an error about some other sections been shifted.